# Why does Angular databinding against factories only work with functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I have the following code:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('controller', controller)
    .factory('storageFactory', storageFactory);

function storageFactory() {
    var message;
    _message = "Message # 1";

    return {
        message: {
            get: function() {
                return _message;
            },
            set: function(value) {
                _message = value;
            },
            value: _message
        }
    }
}

controller.$inject = ['storageFactory'];
function controller(storage) {
    var viewModel = this;
    viewModel.message1 = storage.message.value;
    viewModel.message2 = storage.message.get();
    viewModel.message3 = storage.message.get;
    viewModel.change = change;
    viewModel.revert = revert;

    function change() {
        storage.message.set("Message # 2");
    }
    function revert() {
        storage.message.set("Message # 1");
    }
}
```

And I have the following html:

```
<label>{{controller.message1}}</label>
<label>{{controller.message2}}</label>
<label>{{controller.message3()}}</label>
```

The thing is, that when I run the change and revert methods only the "message3" property changes, Can someone explain why only that one changes? I read something about that angular can only databind against primitives, how true is this? And is there a better way to databind view values to a factory without binding a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting a copy of the value in controller.message1 and controller.message2.  In controller.message3() you are actually executing the get accessor on the message and getting a copy of the latest value.

Comment: That explains part of my problem, is there an easier way to databind than databinding to functions then?

Comment: Why don't you just work with the scope and attach the message directly to the scope?

Comment: the idea is to keep code modular, and for the project I'm going to work on, I need the variable to remain on the service, so that rules out rootScope as well.

Comment: What about exposing the storage on your viewModel and binding to it?  Something like controller.storage.message.value.

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. I had to bind to controller.storage.message.getValue, and yes, I mean databind to a getter method, not the result of the executed getter.